# Extract inputs from a pointer to array of characters

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a command line utility but I cannot find a way to store the commands and arguments. so far I have the following but I get a Segmentation fault:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *command;
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1]; 
    int should_run = 1;

    do{
         cout << "cmd> ";
         int counter = 0;
         while(cin >> command) {
             strcpy(args[counter],command);
             counter++;
         }
        cout << args[0] << "\n";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Use `vector` and `string`. Don't even bother with all your `char *` code.

Comment: Does not compile. Anyway hear of the STL or Boost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault because this:

```
cin >> command
```

tries to write to uninitialized memory. Since this is C++, you should do:

```
std::string command;
```

instead of:

```
char * command;
```

and similarly for `args`. Then you can do `args[counter] = command` instead of using `strcpy()`. For extra points, do `std::vector<std::string> args` instead of using an array, and `args.push_back(command)` instead of `args[counter] = command`.

For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string command;
    std::vector<std::string> args;

    std::cout << "cmd> ";
    while( std::cin >> command ) {
        args.push_back(command);
    }

    int i = 0;
    for ( auto a : args ) {
        std::cout << "Arg " << i++ << " is " << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$ ./args
cmd> test this command
Arg 0 is test
Arg 1 is this
Arg 2 is command
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$
```

Answer (score 2):

A common misconception is that `char *` would play a special role in C or C++, mainly motivated by this being legal:

```
char const * foo = "String";
```

In fact, `char *` is still just a pointer to char, so you would need to allocate memory before being able to assign a string literal to it. You have this problem twice in your code:

```
char * command;
std::cin >> command;
```

and

```
char * arr[N];
std::strcpy(arr[k], command);
```

In C++ you should use containers such as `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>` for this. If you insist on working with char arrays, you can either determine a static maximum length:

```
char command[MAX_LENGTH];
char args[N][MAX_LENGTH];
```

or dynamically using `new[]`

```
char * command = new char[MAX_LENGTH];
char * args[N];
for(unsigned k = 0; k < N; ++k) args[k] = new char[MAX_LENGTH];
```

but then you *must* remember to free that memory as well:

```
delete[] command;
for(unsigned k = 0; k < N; ++k) delete[] args[k];
```

So you should prefer the automatic storage duration unless you have a good reason not to, as you also should have a good reason not to use containers.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
while(cin >> command)
```

is invalid. First of all variable command was not initialized and secondly you have to allocate memory that stream cin could place there data.
Either use a character array (statically or dynamically allocated) or use class std::string for entering data.